# How to amalgamate an array of Nodelists into a single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, nodelist

I have a function that takes elements from the DOM to update a db on button click. Currently, there is one id for one value...

```
 <input class='total' doc-id='12345678' value='${whateverCurrent.value}'>user updates</field>
 <input class='total' doc-id='87654321' value='${whateverCurrent.value}'>user updates</field>
```

This is the function:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.total')
await Promise.all(Array.from(elements).map(async (el) => {
        let docId = el.id;
        let total = el.value;
        await updateDoc(docId, { total });
    }))
```

I now need to break this down such that there are 4 classes of input fields rather than 1 (by quarter). So there will be different elements but with the same id:

```
<input class='q1' doc-id='12345678' value='${whateverCurrent.value}'>user updates</field>
<input class='q2' doc-id='87654321' value='${whateverCurrent.value}'>user updates</field>
<input class='q2' doc-id='12345678' value='${whateverCurrent.value}'>user updates</field>
```

I could run the Promise.all function 4 times, once for each class, but that must be wrong, when instead I should somehow....

```
 // (do something here){
       await updateDoc(docId, {q1, q2, q3, q4})
 }
```

when I take all the elements and put them into an array and look at them in the console, I get an array of 4 NodeLists.

How do I take these 4 nodeLists and amalgamate them so that every id has its 4 values to pass to the update function?

Comment: Use a data attribute like you did with class and target that instead.

Comment: A data attribute of what? The id?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Comment: Sorry yes I know what data-attributes are, I just can't see how it would help me......I mean, the id is already a data attribute, right? Or am I missing something? I think perhaps I'm having a brain fritz from looking at it too long.

Comment: Give every element you want to pick up the same data attribute: `data-id="myattr"`, and then use `querySelectorAll` to select them as _one_ node list: `document.querySelectorAll('input[data-id="myattr"]')` just like you did with the class.

Comment: Your notation for calling the updateDoc function looks wrong, curly braces are used for objects. Do you want to pass an array of numbers to the updateDoc function?

Comment: To create an array of numbers you can use this line: `const values = Array.from(elements).map(e => e.value);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure if this is what you're looking for. Can you be more specific in what the updateDoc function expects as arguments?

Anyway, I coded something that collects all the quarterly values per doc-id and produces an object of following form:

```
{
  1234 :
  {
    q1 : 7
    q2 : 9
  },
  ...
}
```

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('input')
const docsPerQ = {};

elements.forEach(e => {
    const docId = e.getAttribute('doc-id');
    const val = e.value;
    const quarter = e.className;

    if(!(docId in docsPerQ)) docsPerQ[docId] = {};
    
    docsPerQ[docId][quarter] = val;
});

console.log(docsPerQ);
```

```html
<input type="text" class="q1" value="7" doc-id="1234">
<input type="text" class="q1" value="2" doc-id="5678">
<input type="text" class="q2" value="3" doc-id="5678">
<input type="text" class="q2" value="9" doc-id="1234">
```

**EDIT**

I changed the code a bit so the produced output is in a more manageable form. It's now an array of objects with some extra keys attached:

```
[
  {
    docId: 1234,
      quarters: {
        q1: 7,
        q2: 3
      }
  },
  ...
]
```

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const QsPerDoc = [];

elements.forEach(e => {
    const docId = e.getAttribute('doc-id');
    const val = e.value;
    const quarter = e.className;
    const entry = QsPerDoc.find(e => e.docId === docId);

    // find returns undefined if nothing's found. undefined is a falsy value
    if(!entry) {
        let quarters = {};
        quarters[quarter] = val;

        QsPerDoc.push({
            docId : docId,
            quarters
        });
    }
    else {
        entry.quarters[quarter] = val;
    }
});

console.log(QsPerDoc);
```

```html
<input type="text" class="q1" value="7" doc-id="1234">
<input type="text" class="q1" value="2" doc-id="5678">
<input type="text" class="q2" value="3" doc-id="5678">
<input type="text" class="q2" value="9" doc-id="1234">
```

Maybe this works better? Hope it does. I wonder, is the updateDoc function something you can change so it can accept arrays?

You could access them like this:

```
console.log(QsPerDoc[0].docId);
console.log(QsPerDoc[0].quarters.q1);
```

(Note: I also changed the name of the object/array to QsPerDoc instead of DocsPerQ, which was not aplty named)

Anyway I have to get back to work instead of procrastinating on stackoverflow ;)

Comment: Thanks, this got me very close, and with a little tweak the data looks exactly right, but unfortunately I can't figure out how to use it - the only thing I can extract are the id numbers - the object with the figures in, I can't work out how to do anything useful with them except console log them. I might keep playing with it but will prob have to (painfully) run the Promise.all function 4 times for now. Thanks very much for your help.